# Sub Frame Is Not Expanded When Its Parent Is

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()

left_frame_1 = tk.Frame(root, background="#ff0000")
left_frame_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

left_frame_2 = tk.Frame(left_frame_1)
left_frame_2.grid(row=0, column=0)

left_label_1 = tk.Label(left_frame_2, text="HELLO")
left_label_2 = tk.Label(left_frame_2, text="WORLD")
left_label_3 = tk.Label(left_frame_2, text="=D")

left_label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
left_label_2.grid(row=1, column=0)
left_label_3.grid(row=2, column=0)

right_frame1 = tk.Frame(root, background="#00ff00")
right_frame1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

right_frame_2 = tk.Frame(right_frame1, background="#0000ff")
right_frame_2.grid(row=0, column=0)

right_label_1 = tk.Label(right_frame_2, text="CENTER ME!")
right_label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

When my parent frame expands to all its free space, the child frame doesn't, instead it just stays on top.

[image]

---

I've been testing if .grid() has something to do with it, but haven't found anything.

Even if I add sticky="nsew" to both the frame and the label, there is still no change.

```
right_frame1 = tk.Frame(root, background="#00ff00")
right_frame1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

right_frame_2 = tk.Frame(right_frame1, background="#0000ff")
right_frame_2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

right_label_1 = tk.Label(right_frame_2, text="CENTER ME!")
right_label_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

---

My goal is for the parent frame (the one with the green color) to expand to all available space (which I've achieved), and for the child frame containing the label to expand.

[image]

right_frame_2 looks because it expands.

right_frame_1 is not visible because it is completely covered by right_frame_2.

I hope your help, thank you.

Comment: The default for Tkinter widgets is to always occupy no more space than they actually need.  If you want the "CENTER ME!" Label to take up the entire right side of your window, you'd need to apply `sticky="nsew"` to both it and `right_frame_2`.

Comment: I had already tried, but no change.

Comment: Add `sticky="nsew"` to both the `right_frame_2.grid(...)` and the `right_label_1.grid(...)`. If that doesn't work, please add another screenshot showing the problem.

Comment: why are you using both left_frame_1 into left_frame_2? Just remove left_frame_2.

Comment: Is the result shown in last image what you want?

Comment: yes, the result of the last image is my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the result of the last image in the question, you need to:

- change `sticky` options of `.grid()` for `right_frame_2` and `right_label_1`
- set `weight` options of `.rowconfigure()` and `.columnconfigure()` on `root`, `right_frame1` and `right_frame_2`

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()

left_frame_1 = tk.Frame(root, background="#ff0000")
left_frame_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

left_frame_2 = tk.Frame(left_frame_1)
left_frame_2.grid(row=0, column=0)

left_label_1 = tk.Label(left_frame_2, text="HELLO")
left_label_2 = tk.Label(left_frame_2, text="WORLD")
left_label_3 = tk.Label(left_frame_2, text="=D")

left_label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
left_label_2.grid(row=1, column=0)
left_label_3.grid(row=2, column=0)

right_frame1 = tk.Frame(root, background="#00ff00")
right_frame1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

right_frame_2 = tk.Frame(right_frame1, background="#0000ff")
right_frame_2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew") # expand to fill available space

right_label_1 = tk.Label(right_frame_2, text="CENTER ME!")
right_label_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew") # expand horizontally

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) # make left and right frame expand vertically
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1) # make right frame expand horizontally

# allocate all space to right_frame_2
right_frame1.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
right_frame1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# allocate all space of right_frame_2 to right_label_1
right_frame_2.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
right_frame_2.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

When the window is resized:

[image]